# Sparkle updates screwed up in 10.11 (App Transport Security), any workaround?

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-elcapitan, sparkle

Only after releasing an update of my app build for 10.11 Base SDK, I have learned that the app can no longer make NSURLRequests with non-HTTPS protocol, unless specifically white-listed in the app's Info.plist, which I cannot change post factum.

Now the worst thing is that the app has therefore lost the ability to check for updates, and to update. So I cannot provide users with the fix.

They are stuck forever with the last version :( They can only download a newer, fixed version manually, but there's no way to even tell them to do it.

Is there any workaround how I can still distribute the fix, perhaps on server side, or at least tell the people to download it manually?

Thanks.

Comment: That's aggravating. I think you might have to rely on "secondary" network effects: i.e. issue an update quickly which will cover pre-10.11 users and feature this update and the issue prominently on your front page and any support forums to cover 10.11 users. With any luck enough users will talk amongst themselves to get the word out.  Personally as a user I would be understanding as 10.11 has caused some other well intentioned and hopefully temporary issues elsewhere (esp. with SIP).  Also, fortunately manual downloading is still familiar to most users.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can disable the App Transport Security check till you manage to serve your App cast and versions over HTTPS.
In the info.plist file, add the following:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

you may also try this hassle-free build server http://amtourky.me/2016/01/20/mac-os-x-continuous-delivery-sparkler-the-missing-build-server-for-sparkle/